# Twitter API Get Only User Tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I am using Twitter's API to retrieve user tweets (via screen name). However this is returning all "retweets" and random replies to other twitter users. I've been searching through Twitter's API to find a way to ONLY pull back the tweets instead of both tweet & reply but can not find a good solution. Could anyone lend a hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline). Simply add parameters

`exclude_replies=true` & `include_rts=false`

along with your  query. This will filter the retweets and replies!